# Jquery select 1 class after another?

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-selectors

My code:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/jquJs

```
<ul id="menuDots">
    <li id="about1"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
    <li id="about2"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
    <li id="about3"><a href="#"><img class="bulletRoll" src="images/menu-dot.png" /><img src="images/menu-dot-rollover.png" /></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="btn">next btn</div>
```

Right now I have my button set up

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#menuDots li a img.bulletRoll').css({"display":"none"});
});
```

**the problem is that I have 3 sets of buttons but in a different hierarchy,**

1st button - `$('#menuDots li a img.bulletRoll')`, inside the first child of li

2nd button - `$('#menuDots li a img.bulletRoll')`, inside the second child of li

3rd button - `$('#menuDots li a img.bulletRoll')`, inside the third child of li

How do I set `display:none` only to the first `.bulletRoll` only, then the second click will set display none to the next `.bulletRoll`? I have try using `next()` but doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the first of the `.bulletRoll` elements that is still visible:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#menuDots li a img.bulletRoll').filter(':visible').first().css({"display":"none"});
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nqJaI

Also you could use `.hide()` instead of `.css({"display":"none"})`.

Also also I wouldn't recommend using a div element as a "button", because the user can't access it via the keyboard so your page is not accessible for people who can't (or just choose not to) use a mouse or other pointing device. Use an anchor element or a button instead.